# find p,q to the expression A does not depend on x?

Tags: trigonometry

Find $p,q$ to the expression $A = p (\cos^{8}x-\sin^{8}x) + 4(\cos^{6}x-2\sin^{6}x) + q\sin^{4}x$ does not depend upon $x$

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: I think differencing will help.

Comment: I would start by the change of variable $\sin^2x=z^2, cos^2x=1-z^2$ to turn the expression into a polynomial, and cancel the non-constant terms.

Comment: Hint: If $A$ doesn't depend on $x$, you should get the same value for $x = 0, \frac{\pi}2, \pi$ etc.  Substitute and you should get simple equations.  Of course, this does not prove the statement, it just assumes there exists such values...

Comment: It's a difficult problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A=p((1-\sin^2x)^4- \sin^8x) + 4((1-\sin^2x)^3 - 2\sin^6x) + q\sin^4x=\\
=p(\sin^8x - 4\sin^6x + 6\sin^4x - 4\sin^2 x + 1 - \sin^8x) + 4(-\sin^6x + 3\sin^4x -3\sin^2x+1-2\sin^6x) + q\sin^4x = \\
=(-4p-12)\sin^6x + (6p+12+q)\sin^4x + (-4p-12)\sin^2x + p+4.$$

Comment: thanks for help :) I was able to work it

Comment: I solved p=-3 and q=6 ,It's right?

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate and equate to zero, solve for `p,q`. But that works only if the p,q are constants. Else apply $(a^2-b^2)$ formula repeatedly to simplify.